# htmx, push url with form value

Tags: htmx

I've decided to try [htmx](https://htmx.org/). I have a form with a input named `search`, how can I push the input value in the url with [hx-push-url](https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-push-url/)

```
hx-push-url="/?q=
```

Is not clear to me how to do it with plain htmx. Do I need hyperscript?

Answer (score 1):

When generating response (from the search request), you need to add the url into response header called HX-Push-Url, before returning the response in your view (example for django).

```
response['HX-Push-Url'] = "/?q=foobar"
return response
```

Htmx will procees it on response and push whatever url you've added.

Ref:
https://htmx.org/reference/#response_headers

Comment: ok so if i have a form, user have entered some information and i go back... and after come back to this page... form wil be empty?

Answer (score 0):

hx-get and hx-push-url="true" must be sufficient,
just replace the input name from "search" to "q".

```
<form hx-get="/yourresource" hx-push-url="true" hx-params="q">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

if you have other inputs, you can use hx-params="q"
but other inputs will be not passed on the request

```
<form hx-get="/yourresource" hx-push-url="true" hx-params="q">
  <input type="text" name="q" />
  <input type="text" name="otherInput" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

the "otherInput" will not be handled

Ref: https://htmx.org/attributes/hx-params/